# How to read an array of complex numbers from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, complex-numbers

As a learner in c++, I decided to play with complex numbers, using the standard library. Now I need to read and write an array of complex from/to text files. This works simply for writing, without supplemental tricks :

```
void dump(const char *filename){
  ofstream result;
  result.open (filename);
  for(int k=0;k<15;k++){
    result<< outputs[k] <<endl;
  }
  result.close();
}
```

The data are parenthesized and written line by line looking like : (real,im)...

Now, I guess reading (and loading an array of complex) should be as trivial as reading. However, despite my research, I have not found the right way to do that.

My first attempt was naive :

```
void readfile(const char *filename){
  string line;
  ifstream myfile (filename);
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int k=0;
    while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
      k++;
      cout << line << endl;
      inputs[k]= (complex<float>) line; //naive !
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
```

Is there a way to do that simply (without a string parser ) ?

Comment: Well, if there is an `operator<<`, isn't there also `operator>>`?

Comment: So, the functionality offered in [`<complex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), including stream serialization, doesn't already do what you want?

Comment: operator>> is certainly what I need, but how to load the array using this operator ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an `operator<<` for `your_complex_type` (as has been mentioned, `std::complex` provides one), you can use an `istream_iterator`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input( "numbers.txt" );
    std::vector<your_complex_type> buffer{
            std::istream_iterator<your_complex_type>(input), 
            std::istream_iterator<your_complex_type>() };
}
```

This will read all numbers in the file and store them in an `std::vector<your_complex_type>`.

**Edit about your comment**

If you know the number of elements you will read up-front, you can optimize this as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input( "numbers.txt" );
    std::vector<your_complex_type> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(expected_number_of_entries);

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<your_complex_type>(input), 
              std::istream_iterator<your_complex_type>(),
              std::back_inserter(buffer));
}
```

`std::vector::reserve` will make the vector reserve enough memory to store the specified number of elements. This will remove unnecessary reallocations.

You can also use similar code to write your numbers to a file:

```
std::vector<your_complex_type> numbers; // assume this is filled
std::ofstream output{ "numbers.txt" };

std::copy(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers),
          std::ostream_iterator<your_complex_type>(output, '\n') );
```

Comment: I've measured the time it takes to read 10M complex<int> numbers. Your version takes 2.4s, mine takes 1.7s. Is this because your version does more disk accesses?

Comment: It looks like your code allocates the memory for all the elements up-front (at least I see no code handling reallocation in your `readfile`). In my code, the `std::vector` will have to reallocate several times to accomodate additional elements. I have edited the answer to show a way how this can be avoided.

Comment: And by the way, since both versions use an `std::ifstream` the number of disc accesses should be the same, since the stream buffers the reads.

Comment: I've updated my version it appends to `vector<complex<int> >` it takes 1.9s, your version with reserve takes 2.1s. I think the getline caches  in `line` than istream in it's own buffer. (1000 lines each with 10000 numbers)

Comment: Hm, I am not sure what you are saying. However, if that performance is really that important, you should use profiler to determine exactly which operation is the bottleneck there.

Comment: if there are 10M numbers on 10M lines, my version takes 15s yours still takes 2.2s

Answer (score 4):

C++ version:

```
std::complex<int> c;
std::ifstream fin("filename");
fin>>c;
```

C version:

```
int a,b;
FILE *fin=fopen("filename","r");
fscanf(fin,"(%d,%d)\n",&a,&b);
```

C++ read multiple lines with multiple complex values on each line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
int main ()
{
    std::complex<int> c;
    std::ifstream fin("test.in");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::complex<int> > vec;
    vec.reserve(10000000);
    while(std::getline(fin,line))
    {
        std::stringstream stream(line);
        while(stream>>c)
        {
           vec.push_back(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please put the C++ answer as the first one

Comment: But how to feed an array this way ?

Comment: @JCLL use `std::vector`